# How to update MongoDB from Pandas Dataframe by using bulk operation?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I import data from MongoDB to Pandas which I use to work with the data. Once the data has been changed in Pandas I want to update the DB which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'initialize_unordered_bulk_op' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Not sure if I´m missing an import or if something else is wrong here. Is there a better solution to update data in bulk?

I use [unordered-bulk-write-operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations)
My Dataframe looks kinda like this:

```
_id, CHANNELNAME, USERNAME, DATETIME,
62fbd1ce819cb9e664961463, s, bf, 2022-01-01
62fbd1ce819cb9e664961463, d, bd, 2022-01-01
62fbd1ce819cb9e664961463, f, bs, 2022-01-01
```

I use this code to update the DB

```
date_selected = df.loc[df[search_column].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)]

bulk_update = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for index, row in date_selected.iterrows():
    _id=row['_id']
    new_value=row['CHANNELNAME']
    bulk_update.find({'_id':_id}).update_one({'$set':{'CHANNELNAME':new_value}})
bulk_update.execute()
```